# Таблица pandas криво выводится в телеграм-ботЮ созданном на aiogram. Как можно отформатировать таблицу?

Tags: python, pandas, aiogram

Вот мой код с `pandas`:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


def SWHL_sniper():
    url = "http://www.swhl.ru/tournament/1026071/stats?common=1"
    response = requests.get(url)
    df_list = pd.read_html(response.text)
    return df_list[0]


print(SWHL_sniper())
```

Вот код запуска скрипта:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=["commands"])
async def com(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Команды SWHL:\n{statistics_player.SWHL_sniper()}")
```

[image: А это кривой вывод бота]

Comment: Как вариант можно через html сделать. При выводе юзеру просто указать parsemode HTML.
[ссылка](https://alexeyseleznev.wordpress.com/2020/04/30/python-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-html-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-pa/)

Comment: @LevTikhonov, к сожалению, это не помогло

Comment: @LevTikhonov, вы были правы, всё вышло. Только ещё нужно было обернуть функцию в теги <pre></pre>